# How to change prestashop theme dynamically

Tags: themes, prestashop

I would like to establish an alternative theme for all my website visitors except for me.

If is not possible natively or by a module I would like to know where I can add a little conditions code that will redefine the theme during the page loading.

Thankz for your help

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it seem that is not possible.

Setting Maintenance mode is the only way for do this kind of thing.